# Stripe Proration Webhook Interception on Downgrades

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I'm looking for a way to ensure on a plan downgrade, the user gets charged the plans price on the next payment period.

If susan is going from $20/month to a $10/month plan, she continues to get the benefits of the $20/month until end of her subscription plan. However, on stripe UI it says she pays $0 for next month and I'm guessing it's because of proration.

I've tried to modify the subscription on 'customer.subscription.updated' but the subscription doesn't show the change in the stripe subscription UI or customer portal.

What else can I do besides make my own user flow for checking out and upgrading/downgrading the plans?

Answer (score 0):

That $0 invoice is a result of proration, because the customer has already paid more than they should.

If you want your customer to pay $10 in the next billing cycle, you should disable proration (by setting [proration_behavior](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-proration_behavior) to `none`) when updating the subscription with a new price.

Comment: So I've tried doing that when they update the subscription using the webhook, but it didn't propagate to the UI or the subscription data.